# Creating a hierarchy from text

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, hierarchy

I'm trying to create a hierarchy from a text field I have in my table.

Visually it is relatively easy to see who is parent and child.

For example: (*see a screenshot of the table results*)

```
1M
-----1M5
----------1M5.5445
----------1M5.6
AC
-----AC
----------AC.1
----------AC.2
----------AC.3
AD
-----AD.1
-----AD.2
-----AD.3
```

Note that the dot in the string is not always present and constant.

How can I proceed in order to build this hierarchy of parent, child which can have several levels?

[image]

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP2-GDR) (KB3194719) - 11.0.5388.0 (X64)

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)

Comment: @AndriyM TYou understand the main goal here... You provide me a really good base. I will start from your code and optimise it with ID / row_number. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps adding some sort of row ID would help with finding a more robust solution than [this atrocity](https://dbfiddle.uk/ir4HNSKM):

```
CREATE TABLE
  dbo.SomeData
(
  CODE_ACT varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO
  dbo.SomeData (CODE_ACT)
VALUES
  ('1M')
, ('1M5')
, ('1M5.5445')
, ('1M5.6')
, ('AT')
, ('AC')
, ('AC.1')
, ('AC.2')
, ('AC.3')
, ('AD')
, ('AD.1')
, ('AD.2')
, ('AD.3')
;
```

```
WITH
  Hierarchical AS
  (
    SELECT
      this.CODE_ACT
    , PARENT_CODE = x.CODE_ACT
    FROM
      dbo.SomeData AS this
      OUTER APPLY
      (
        SELECT TOP (1)
          that.CODE_ACT
        FROM
          dbo.SomeData AS that
        WHERE
          this.CODE_ACT LIKE that.CODE_ACT + '_%'
        ORDER BY
          that.CODE_ACT DESC
      ) AS x
  )
, Recursive AS
  (
    SELECT
      CODE_ACT
    , PARENT_CODE
    , Level = 0
    FROM
      Hierarchical
    WHERE
      PARENT_CODE IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      ch.CODE_ACT
    , ch.PARENT_CODE
    , par.Level + 1
    FROM
      Hierarchical AS ch
      INNER JOIN Recursive AS par ON ch.PARENT_CODE = par.CODE_ACT
  )
SELECT
  Item = REPLICATE('--', Level) + CODE_ACT
FROM
  Recursive
ORDER BY
  CODE_ACT
;
```

Output:

| Item |
| --- |
| 1M |
| --1M5 |
| ----1M5.5445 |
| ----1M5.6 |
| AC |
| --AC.1 |
| --AC.2 |
| --AC.3 |
| AD |
| --AD.1 |
| --AD.2 |
| --AD.3 |
| AT |

<sub>Contributed by https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6965</sub>